# Accessing database postgresql : password authentification failed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm new to postgreSQL (and SQL btw). I'm trying to connect to a database locally.
So here are the commands i'm using :

```
create user adeyris;
alter user antoine with login;
alter user antoine with encrypted password '123';
alter user antoine with createdb;
create database cpf_ietest;
```

I now leave psql, and load my dump like this :

```
psql -h localhost -U antoine -d cpf_ietest -f /home/antoine/Downloads/cpf_ietest.sql
```

I am asked for my password, i type 123, and i get the following error :

> psql: FATAL: password authentification failed for user "antoine"

Here is my pg_hba.conf file :

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

In the first uncommented line, I modified 'peer' to 'md5'.
I run on Ubuntu 16.04 and postgresql 9.5.

Thanks for your help,
Antoine

Answer (score 0):

is 123 is your database password if not then enter ur database password 
which you have given at the time of installing the Postgres

Comment: 123 is the password i gave to the user antoine with
    alter user antoine with password '123'

Comment: Oh and i also used :
grant all privileges on database cpf_ietest to antoine;

Answer (score 0):

1. In Md5 Method use database password which you have given at the time of Installation of PostgreSQL.
2. Check whether password exits in .pgpass files or not.
3. Peer authentication work with OS postgres user, So check weather OS User Must be enable with NOPASSWD
4. Last you can use trust authentication method for local connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't remember giving a password at the time of installation, how can I retrieve it ?

Comment: Check in .pgpass file in postgres home directory

Comment: Ok so in /etc/postgresql/9.5/main I don't have any file named .pgpass, is that where it's supposed to be ?

Comment: in case file doesn't exits then you can manually create it and use it. https://serverfault.com/questions/285219/pgpass-with-postgresql-not-working

Comment: Ok, i'm trying what you told me